# lambda key and sorting in python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have difficulties with understanding:

```
key = lambda x: x[1]
list = [(i,sum(1 for y in lower_letters if y==i))

l.sort(cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x[1],y[1]))) #only 2.x???
        cmp(a,b)
```

Does it return anything unlike '.sort'?
Can someone explain me what it supposed to do?
Why we just don't use somthing like list.sort()?

I don't really know what x,y means, that's what my teacher wrote and I'm trying to guess what she meant

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: 1) `key` is not used anywhere. Why is it defined? 2) Don't name a variable `list`, this is a builtin function. 3) What is `l`?

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in the documentation for the [sort behavior](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted)

> `cmp` specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (iterable elements) which should return a negative, zero or positive number depending on whether the first argument is considered smaller than, equal to, or larger than the second argument: cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x.lower(), y.lower()). The default value is None.

And the documentation for the built int [`cmp` function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#cmp)

> Compare the two objects x and y and return an integer according to the outcome. The return value is negative if x < y, zero if x == y and strictly positive if x > y.

Answer (score 0):

@PalKol your question is not clear enough..

From what i understand, you want to know how to sort using `key = lambda ...`?

I may give some examples :

You have a list of tuples, `l = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,1), (2, 3)]`.

1. If you use `sorted(l)`, this will sort the list by the first element of each tuple, which result in `[(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (5,1)]`.
2. If you want to sort by the 2nd element, use `sorted(l, key = lambda x: x[1])`, which will result `[(5,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]`. No.1 is also equivalent as `sorted(l, key = lambda x: x[0])`.
3. If you want to sort by the sum : use `sorted(l, key = sum)`, which will result in `[(1,2), (2,3), (5,1), (3,4)]`.

*The 3 examples above sort from lowest to highest.